# Two buttons of Android widgets calling same Activity with different intents

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a homescreenwidget in Android with two buttons. Both buttons should call the same activity ( class ) just use a different intent  plus intent extras, to know which button called the class. 
For now only button1 is working and calling the activity. I also receive the keyvalue in the called Activity.

How can i make the second button work?
Here's my code:

```
             public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    for ( int i =0; i<appWidgetIds.length ; i++){

        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, Main.class);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, Main.class);

        // Intent put extras Button 1
        String bread1 = "secure";
        Bundle basket1 = new Bundle();
        basket1.putString("key", bread1);
        intent1.putExtras(basket1);

        // Intent put extras Button 2
        String bread2 = "insecure";
        Bundle basket2 = new Bundle();
        basket2.putString("key", bread2);
        intent2.putExtras(basket2);

        PendingIntent pending1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intent1, 0);
        PendingIntent pending2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent2, 0);

        RemoteViews views1 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.maina);
        RemoteViews views2 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.maina);

        views1.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, pending1);
        views2.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, pending2);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views1);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views2);
```

here is the maina.xml

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <LinearLayout
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1"                android:orientation="vertical">
          <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"   android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/tvWidget"  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"></TextView>

           <LinearLayout
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1"  android:orientation="horizontal">



           <Button android:text="@string/button1" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></Button>
            <Button android:text="@string/button2" android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></Button>

          </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you provide further details on what isn't working for the second button?  I.e. it is not doing anything at all when clicked on?

Comment: right, its not doing anything at all when its clicked.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

@Arnold you have created 2 PendingIntent which are....

```
PendingIntent pending1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intent1, 0);
PendingIntent pending2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent2, 0);
```

Where PendingIntent.getActivity(Context context, int requestCode, Intent intent, int flags) has 4 parameters. You have to send different "**requestCode**" for different PendingIntents.

Your code should be....

```
PendingIntent pending1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
PendingIntent pending2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

in the main class you need to create this...

```
String value;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Bundle b=intent.getExtras();


    try{
    value=b.getString("key");
    }
     catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

    super.onReceive(context, intent);

}
```

with the onUpdate code....

```
    @Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    // Get all ids
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,
            main.class);
    int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

    for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {
        // Create some random data

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.main);


        // Register an onClickListener for 1st button
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, main.class);

        intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS,allWidgetIds);
        intent.putExtra("key", "1st Button");

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, pendingIntent);

        // Register an onClickListener for 2nd button............
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, main.class);

           intent2.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
                   intent2.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS,allWidgetIds);
           intent2.putExtra("key", "2nd Button");

        PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                1, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, pendingIntent2);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }
}
```

Then you can check whether **value=1st Button** or **value=2nd Button** to know which Button has been clicked.
It should work... IF it does not work please let me know what is the problem...

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with using 2 buttons on a widget. I set OnClickPendingIntents on both of them, distinguished by different setExtra() calls. But only the latter intent was called, even when clicking the first button. 
I found 2 solutions:
- assign different actions to both PendingIntents
- on the second PendingEvent set the PendingEvent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT flag

I am quite unfamiliar with PendingEvents and Widgets, so I can't see the pros and cons and will stick to the first solution.

Maybe that might help you with your problem, too.

Answer (score 1):

Your widget will only have 1 remote view.  Try changing the end of your code snippet to:

```
RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.maina);

remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, pending1);
remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, pending2);

appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteView);
```

Failing that, it would be useful to see your layout in `R.layout.maina`.

Comment: i changed the code like you mentioned. it doesnt work as well. the button2 has no functionality. the button changes the colour when you click on it but it doesnt start the desired activity. thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry Arnold, can't spot the problem other than to point out that you're missing a close `</LinearLayout>` tag in your maina.xml.  However, I suspect this is a copy and paste issue as Eclipse should have flagged this as an error otherwise.  Good luck (and post the answer back here if you figure it out)!

Answer (score 1):

In my case:

```
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_head, touch_man(context));
```

remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_head2, touch_woman(context));

```
public static PendingIntent touch_man(Context context) {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("touch_man");
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

}

public static PendingIntent touch_woman(Context context) {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("touch_woman");
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

}
```

In AndroidManifest

```
<receiver
        android:name="Receiver"
        android:label="widgetBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="touch_man" />
            <action android:name="touch_woman"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/demo_widget_provider" />
    </receiver>
```

It's working.