# Two buttons with PendingIntents - Widget

Tags: android, android-intent, widget, android-pendingintent

I'm creating a widget with two buttons.
One of them updates the content of the widget and the second one must launch an activity.

I have two PendingIntent for each action, but I can't make them both work. If one works the other one doesn't.

I've revised the code and can't understand what's wrong.

Any help will be very appreciated.

This is the code.

```
    RemoteViews controls = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.miwidget);

    Intent intent = new Intent("actony.com.ACTUALIZAR_WIDGET");
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);


    Intent intentSettings = new Intent();  
    intentSettings.setClass(context,WidgetConfig.class);  


    PendingIntent pendingIntentUpdate = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, widgetId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    controls.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.BtnActualizar, pendingIntentUpdate);

    PendingIntent pendingIntentSettings =  PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentSettings, 0);
    controls.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.botonSettings, pendingIntentSettings);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the getActivity PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT aswell...

```
 PendingIntent pendingIntentSettings =  
      PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentSettings, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

and if multiple widget's are possible add the widgetId there too.

Make sure both of the activities/broadcasts are listed in the manifest file.

Moreover, try creating the Intent with this constructor:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context,ACTUALIZAR_WIDGET.class);
 Intent intentSettings = new Intent(context,WidgetConfig.class);
```

add imports if needed.

Hope some of that will make you widget work.

Answer (score 2):

Check this link to know which button has been clicked when there is two or more button in a widget..

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10733049/1331593

It should work... IF it does not work please let me know what is the problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
Intent read = new Intent(ctx, NotificationClick.class);
read.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
read.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "READ");
PendingIntent readInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 1, read, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

Intent reply = new Intent(ctx, NotificationClick.class);
reply.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
reply.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "REPLY");
PendingIntent replyInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 2, reply, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

NotificationManagerCompat nMgr = NotificationManagerCompat.from(ctx);
Notification newMessageNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx, "MESSAGE_CHANNEL")
  .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.user_account)
  .setContentTitle(contact)
  .setContentText(text)
  .addAction(R.drawable.drafts, "Read", readInt)
  .addAction(R.drawable.drafts, "Reply", replyInt)
  .setGroup(MESSAGE_GROUP)
  .build();
nMgr.notify(100, newMessageNotification);
```